# ExcelJS: Javascript Heap Out of memory when processing 100+ MB data

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

I'm trying to create an excel file with 100+ MB data using `exceljs`. Everything is fine from processing the data, creating columns and sheets, but the problem comes when writing the file using `workbook.xlsx.writeFile(filepath)` which the error was `javascript heap out of memory` coming from the library. I have already increase the `max-old-space-size` to 16384 and it still crashing. I wonder if there are any solid solutions or workarounds to make this issue resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you should use streams instead of trying to save the whole content at once:

```
const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
await workbook.xlsx.write(fileStream);
```